# PHP, fpdf, damaged file download

Tags: php, file, mysqli, fpdf

I try to save some datas from MYSQLi to pdf. File is download by browser, but when i try to open it, Adobe shouts me "It's damaged". Here is my code:

```
ob_start();
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('A4');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',16);
$line="Użytkownik: ".$login." Miesiąc: ".$miesiac." Dzień: ".$dzien;
$pdf->Cell(0,5,$line);
$query="select * from ".$prefix."_Przychody where Login='$login'";
$start=mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($dane=mysqli_fetch_assoc($start))
{
    $data=date("Y-m-").$dzien;
    if($dane['Data']==$data)
    {
        $line="Opis: ".$dane['Opis']." Kategoria: ".$dane['Kategoria_przychodu']." Kwota: ".$dane['Kwota'].".";
        $pdf->Cell(0,5,$line);
        $y = $pdf->GetY();
        $pdf->SetXY(0,$y+10);
    }
}

$query="select * from ".$prefix."_Wydatki where Login='$login'";
$start=mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($dane=mysqli_fetch_assoc($start))
{
    $data=date("Y-m-").$dzien;
    if($dane['Data']==$data)
    {
        $line="Opis: ".$dane['Opis']." Kategoria: ".$dane['Kategoria_przychodu']." Kwota: ".$dane['Kwota'].".";
        $pdf->Cell(0,5,$line);
        $y = $pdf->GetY();
        $pdf->SetXY(0,$y+10);

    }
}
$name=$login.".pdf";
$pdf->Output('D',$name,true);   
ob_end_flush();
```

BTW. I try save datas for some date, and sorry for use Polish name, but it's no my Database :D

Comment: If you save the PDF to disk on the server, can you open the generated PDF then, on the server, or if you FTP it to your system?

Comment: PS: You dont need the `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()`, maybe thats causing a problem

Comment: Ya when i save it on server i can open it, but i need to save it on local computer

Comment: Without it fpdf.php file making fatal error

Comment: Its never given me an error. So maybe there is some other code in this script that is causing some issues

Comment: This is this errors: FPDF->Error('Some data has a...'), FPDF->_checkoutput(),  FPDF->Output('D', 'user.pdf', true) and it doesnt save file

Comment: Message of error: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i create pdf file and save it to my server. This file is ok, i can open it and read in Adobe, but when i try to save it on local computer and open, adobe again shouts me its broken. In the post above is my code to create pdf file and here is my code to download it from server to local computer:

```
if($zapis==1)
{
$file = $login.".pdf";
if(!$file){
header('Location: index.php?w=laczne_podsumowanie');
}
else
{
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
}
}
```

Now how i can edit code to download not damaged pdf file.
I will be grateful for any answer.
Peace :)

EDIT: i repair this by use:

```
flush();
ob_clean();
```

before:

```
readfile($file);
```